# access arguments similar to this.variable

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
  doStuff("foo");
}

void doStuff(String myString) {
  String myString = "bar";
  print(myString); //prints "bar"
}
```

The above executed in the dartpad yields "bar", the local variable is used instead of the parameter in the last line. If instead of an argument myString were an instance variable of a class, we could access the original myString with this.myString to print "foo". Is there an analogous way to access an argument to a function after a homonymous local variable has been declared?

Comment: No, there is no way to disambiguate the shadowed variable.  You would need to use different variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For local variables, you are expected to be able to rename any local variable which shadows the variable you want to access, so there is no scope override.

For instance variables, you can use `this.x`, for static variables you can use `ClassName.x`, for an imported top-level name, you can import the library with a fresh prefix name and access it as `prefix.x`, and for public top-level variable of the *current* library, you can, if all else fails, import that library with a prefix too and use:

```dart
// library foo.dart
import "foo.dart" as toplevel; // <- this library!
// ...
int foo = 42;
// ...
int method(int foo) {
 return toplevel.foo + foo; // Wohoo
```

For local variables, you just have to rename the one that's shadowing the variable you want. Since nobody can see local variables from outside the method, no-one will ever know.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I expected, but wasn't quite sure about since in my book this would warrant a warning like "The value of the local variable ... isn't used." for the argument, which doesn't appear.